# No Se Pudo Conectar Con El Servidor: Hubo Algun Error

Tags: php, mysql

Al intentar conectar desde PHP al servidor me aparece el siguiente mensaje:

> ```
> No Se Pudo Conectar Con El Servidor: Hubo Algun Error.
> ```

El código php es el siguiente:

```
<?php
    //conectamos Con el servidor
    $conectar=@mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
    //verificamos la conexion
    if(!$conectar){
        echo"No Se Pudo Conectar Con El Servidor";
    }else{

        $base=mysql_select_db('prueba');
        if(!$base){
            echo"No Se Encontro La Base De Datos";          
        }
    }
    //recuperar las variables
    $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
    $domicilio=$_POST['domicilio'];
    $telefono=$_POST['telefono'];
    $correo=$_POST['correo'];
    $mensaje=$_POST['mensaje'];
    //hacemos la sentencia de sql
    $sql="INSERT INTO datos VALUES('$nombre',
                                    '$domicilio',
                                    '$telefono',
                                   '$correo',
                                   '$mensaje')";
    //ejecutamos la sentencia de sql
    $ejecutar=mysql_query($sql);
    //verificamos la ejecucion
    if(!$ejecutar){
        echo"Hubo Algun Error";
    }else{
        echo"Datos Guardados Correctamente<br><a href='contacto.html'>Volver</a>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: deberías revisar los puertos que tienes configurados en mysql, si el usuario `root` tiene contraseña... [mysql_connect](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-connect.php)

Comment: no deberías estar usando las funciones **mysql_()** pues están obsoletas y por tanto son inseguras, por otro lado seguro que tu user no tiene contraseña asignada?

Comment: Como bien indican los compañeros las funciones `mysql_*` están obsoletas en su lugar se debería utilizar la librería y funciones de **MySQLi**, en PHP 7 ya han sido eliminadas esas funciones, pero no sabemos si el error es por que la función no existe o por otro motivo ya que estas silenciando los errores al anteponer la `@` a la función. Empieza por eliminar la @ es una mala práctica.

Answer (score 0):

Estas utilizando `mysql`*(obsoleto)* en lugar de `mysqli`. Tu código debería ir así:

```
<?php
    //conectamos Con el servidor
    $conectar=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');
    //verificamos la conexión
    if(!$conectar){
        echo"No Se Pudo Conectar Con El Servidor";
    }else{
        $base=mysqli_select_db('prueba');
        if(!$base){
            echo"No Se Encontró La Base De Datos";          
        }
    }
    //recuperar las variables
    $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
    $domicilio=$_POST['domicilio'];
    $telefono=$_POST['telefono'];
    $correo=$_POST['correo'];
    $mensaje=$_POST['mensaje'];
    //hacemos la sentencia de sql
    $sql="INSERT INTO datos VALUES('$nombre',
                                '$domicilio',
                                '$telefono',
                                '$correo',
                                '$mensaje')";
    //ejecutamos la sentencia de sql
    $ejecutar=mysqli_query($sql);
   //verificamos la ejecución
   if(!$ejecutar){
        echo"Hubo Algún Error";
    }else{
        echo"Datos Guardados Correctamente<br><a href='contacto.html'>Volver</a>";
    }
```

Y otro tema no menos importante, tu código es vulnerable a inyección SQL. Busca información acerca de esto y observa la importancia de las consultas preparadas.[Manual consultas preparadas](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Un saludo

Comment: aunque cierto lo que no usar `mysql` un error de ese tipo no es por que lo use, va mas primero a saber si su gestor se conecta sin contraseña o si esta corriendo en el puerto 3306

Comment: estoy de acuerdo contigo

Comment: entonces primero hay que esperar a que nos aclare eso el OP

Comment: cierto, aunque normalmente, en local, si no se modifica nada el usuario root tiene la contraseña en blanco. De todos modos, como dices, esperemos a que el OP nos claro eso.